# Mi Piston Air earphone not working on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: sound, headphones

This is very frustrating indeed... back when I used Mint I couldn't use earphone on my PC, and now on Ubuntu it's the same. I couldn't get my old earphones to work on my Windows 7 either...

In the meantime I have just bought a pair of new earphones, and I was hoping that this might work...

But it didn't. I have tried the usual troubleshooting according to other this site and other forums and sites, but I'm still unable to hear anything on my earphones...

I found a thread on a forum that has been solved with a similar issue.

I was wondering if my issue could be solved in the same way, and that's why I'm posting...

I'm not sure as to how should I apply that method on my system, so I was hoping you guys might help...

Here's the link to that thread:

[Link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1774627)

Here are some relevant data that might help:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [8086:8c20] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller [1043:8576]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:8c10] (rev d5)
```

And:

```
pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

This is how alsamixer looks right now:

[image]

Should I do anything here?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Added the outputs and the current state of my alsamixer...

Comment: @DavidFoerster It seems that I can only get my earphones working when I plug them in the same port where my main speakers are plugged in...

I have three audio ports at the back of my CU box, and my speaker is plugged in the middle one labeled "LINE OUT"- this is the port where I can my earphones to work too; at the front of my CU there are two ports with symbols of a microphone and a headphone but none of those work with my earphone or the speakers...

Maybe the front ports aren't connected internally to the CU, that seems to be the only explanation...!

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've enabled everything, as you can see from the picture of the alsamixer above(I've just edited)... I even tried changing the channel...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66146/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-apollonius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some muted channels (see the `MM` symbol below them), most notably the *Headphone* channel.

- You can unmute them if you select them with the arrow keys and press <kbd>M</kbd>, so that the symbol below the volume meter shows `00`.
- Alternatively you can use `gnome-alsamixer` from the [eponymous package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-alsamixer/) (which has a point-and-click graphical user interface) to do the same.